# Table view creation in flutter using dart

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create tableview in flutter,but cant find any  examples which i can understand. Can someone please provide a simple example.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow. Consider asking in https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter, Google groups, ...

Answer (score 1):

Instruction and syntax exist on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

```
 Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
      children: [
        TableRow(children: [
          Text('Cell 1'),
          Text('Cell 2'),
          Text('Cell 3'),
        ]),
        TableRow(children: [
          Text('Cell 4'),
          Text('Cell 5'),
          Text('Cell 6'),
        ])
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Table`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html).

I give up using table in my App.

But I found a example on github for you through google: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/data_table_demo.dart

Comment: Still waiting on the details ;)

Comment: @Ferdz find a demo for you.

Comment: that link has been removed ;)

Comment: I stopped develop using Flutter. Anyone can edit this answer.